# Load data into bootstrap table

Tags: java, spring-boot, bootstrap-4

I'm developing a spring-boot application for an academic project, right now what i need is to load some data (from mongolab) to a bootstrap table. I'm using the MVC pattern. The data will be retrieved from the database and filtered through a criteria (name of employee) and those filtered documents need to be in a table.

My controller method:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "listarFichajesEmpleado", method = RequestMethod.POST) 
public String listarFichajesEmpleado(HttpServletRequest request,Model model) throws Exception {     
    Usuario usuario;
    //Getting the identification of the employee to search through the database, name to be exact
    usuario = (Usuario) request.getSession().getAttribute(usuario_conect); 
    String nombreEmpleado = usuario.getNombre();

    //creating the list of corresponding data related to the specific employee
    List<Document> listaFichajes = new ArrayList<Document>();
    //getFichajesEmpleado() will retrieve that data from the DB through the DAO class
    listaFichajes = usuario.getFichajesEmpleado(nombreEmpleado);

    // this is where i think i would add the data to the jsp file
    model.addAttribute("fichajes", listaFichajes);

    return "fichajes"; //returning the fichajes.jsp file again
    }
```

JSP form- Just a simple table to test it first, located in fichajes.jsp

```
<form action="listarFichajesEmpleado" method="post">
    <table class="table table-dark" align="center">
        <thead class="thead">
            <tr>
                <th scope="col">Fecha</th>
                <th scope="col">Entrada</th>
                <th scope="col">Salida</th>
                <th scope="col">Estado</th>

            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <c:forEach items="${fichajes}" var="fichaje">
                <tr>
                    <td>${fichaje.fechaFichaje}</td>
                    <td>${fichaje.horaFichaje}</td>
                    <td>${fichaje.horaCierre}</td>
                    <td>${fichaje.estado}</td>
                </tr>
            </c:forEach>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</form>
```

I dont think the model class is really relevant because as a said in this line of code:

```
listaFichajes = usuario.getFichajesEmpleado(nombreEmpleado);
```

the data is retreived from the database successfully and is a list of mongo Documents with this structure:

```
nombreEmpleado -- name of employee just needed to search on DB
fechafichaje   -- date of the sign in 
horaentrada    -- entry time
horasalida     -- exit time
estado         -- state of the check in (true or false)
```

But the problem is that no information would show up on the table.

My knowledge of spring-boot and the MVC pattern is really limited (specially  in controller classes and how models and views work with them) so any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the taglib for the jstl:

Add this to your jsp file:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
```

Don´t forget to import the jar into your pom/gradle file: (I'm using gradle)

```
compile group: 'javax.servlet', name: 'jstl', version: '1.2'
```

Output: (I just put some fields to show you)

[image]